# Database web frontend php, ajax, js

Tags: ajax, database, frontend

My skills in Java/AJAX are relatively poor. I am looking for a method  or example link, that would enable the creation of a postgresql front end, that displays a record, the user clicks submit to edit the record changes. and Next to view the next one. The record would be shown within the text boxes within the page as it does when it is first created.

Comment: There's a cazillion ways to do this! If you don't want to write it yourself, you might use an [MVC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) such as [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), or perhaps go with a CMS like WordPress.